# Importing each line from text file from Resources in Unity to list in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a text file in my Assets/Resources/Text, on `Start()` I want to import each line from the text file as a string in list. Using this code does it for me,

```
string[] AllWords = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\jamal\Downloads\English\english-words-master\New folder\AllWords.txt");
        listOfWords = new List<string>(AllWords);
```

But how do I do the same when the file is in my Resources folder, I can't seem to use `File.ReadAllLines`.

Any help would be of great help, thank you!

The text file contains all the words in a dictionary, here's how the text file goes:

```
aahed
aahing
aahs
aal
aalii
aaliis
aals
aam
aani
aardvark
aardvarks
aardwolf
aardwolves
aargh
aaron
aaronic
aaronical
aaronite
aaronitic
```

Comment: `But how do I do the same when the file is in my Resources folder, I can't seem to use File.ReadAllLines` please update post to include what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with [**Don't use `Reources`!**](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b5a7)

If against Unity's own recommendation you still want to do it for some reason then you have to load that resource using [`Resources.Load`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) in your case as a [`TextAsset`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextAsset.html) like e.g.

```
// assuming your path is e.g. "Assets/Resources/Text/AllWords.txt"
var file = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("Text/AllWords");
var content = file.text;
var AllWords = content.Split("\n");
listOfWords = new List<string>(AllWords);
```

---

The better approach though would probably be to listen to what Unity recommends and instead of using `Resources` at all rather place your file into the [`Assets/StreamingAssets`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html) folder and access it later via [`Application.streamingAssetsPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html)

either using as you did

```
string[] AllWords = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "AllWords.txt");
listOfWords = new List<string>(AllWords);
```

Or - depending on the platform, e.g. in Android you can't directly access the `StreamingAssets`

```
StartCoroutine(LoadWords());

...

private IEnumerator GetRequest()
{
    var url = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "AllWords.txt");
    using (var webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
    {
        // Request and wait for result
        yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

        switch (webRequest.result)
        {    
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.Success:
                var content = webRequest.downloadHandler.text;
                var AllWords = content.Split("\n");
                listOfWords = new List<string>(AllWords);
                break;

            default:
                Debug.LogError($"Failed loading file \"{url}\" - {webRequest.error}", this);
                break;
         }
    }
}
```

---

You could actually also simply put your file into a "normal" folder like `Assets/AllWords.txt` and then directly reference it via the Inspector in a

```
public TextAsset file;
```

or

```
[SerializeField] private TextAsset file;
```

and then access the content via

```
var content = file.text;
var AllWords = content.Split("\n");
listOfWords = new List<string>(AllWords);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This did it. I didn't even know that you could reference any file from the inspector. And with this, my base game is finally done :) Just need to work on the other UI now. Thanks again, cheers!

Comment: @JamalH.A Glad to help! :) That's what StackOverflow is about for me: Help others to actually learn something new instead of only fix an issue ;)